# One-to-many Joins on two txt files in ArcGIS Pro - GTFS

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, general-transit-feed-specification

I want to work on a GTFS project and trying to figure out if I can perform all my data engineering processes in ArcGIS Pro without having to go to some external tools to perform joins.

What I want to do is to get a table of unique routes with points.

I added both files but when I validate the join, it can't perform it:

[image]

Comment: I'm not you can join a text file to a text file as neither have an objectid field. Convert the text files to file geodatabase tables then attempt the join on those?

Comment: How do I convert them?

Comment: The Table to Table conversion tool will convert text into tables.